# VHDL 1 tick Clock delay on signal and 2 ticks on another

Tags: vhdl, delay, clock

Can someone explain to me why my count has a one tick delay and my sum has 2 tick delay? I'm a beginner, so this may seem trivial to some, but I really don't understand the problem. This emulates how a single type coin storage entity should behave in the case of an automatic food distributor. 
Initially, I thought the 1 tick delay of the sum compared to the count could be due to 2 signals being in 2 different clock processes, but that doesn't seem to be it. Given that a sequential code is required here, I don't know how I could at least reduce the overall delay by 1 tick for each signal. It would be ideal if both have no delay.
Thanks for checking this problem out.

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
 use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
 use work.fixed_point_pkg.all;

 entity single_coin_type_storage is
 generic(INIT_COUNT : natural;
    --Number of coins loaded at maintenance.
    INIT_SUM   : unsigned(15 downto 0);
    --Value of the coins loaded at maintenance.
    COIN_VAL   : unsigned(15 downto 0));
    --Value of a single coin.
 port(clk     : in std_logic;
    --System clock.
    reset    : in std_logic;
    --System reset.
    en       : in std_logic;
    --Enable input. When low, no register updates can
    --happen and the output of >>count<< should be zero.
    add_coin : in std_logic;
    --Signals that a coin is being added.
    rem_coin : in std_logic;
    --Signals that a coin is being removed.
    count    : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
    --Number of coins currently stored. If >>en<< is low,
    --must be zero.
    sum      : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    --Value of all coins currently stored. Should be
    --output at all times, regardless of >>en<<.
    fault    : out std_logic);
    --Signals that an attempt to insert a coin into a full
    --storage unit or to remove it from an empty unit is 
    --being made.
end entity single_coin_type_storage;

architecture rtl of single_coin_type_storage is

signal counter_reg: unsigned(5 downto 0);
signal en_vec: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
signal sum_reg: unsigned(15 downto 0);

signal y_count : unsigned(5 downto 0);
signal y_sum   : unsigned(15 downto 0);

signal ovf ,internal_en: std_logic;
begin
y_count <=  counter_reg +1 when (add_coin ='1') else
        counter_reg - 1 when (rem_coin ='1') else 
        counter_reg ;

ovf <= y_count(5);

internal_en <= en and (not ovf);
en_vec <= (others=>en);

y_sum <= sum_reg + COIN_VAL when (add_coin ='1') else
     sum_reg - COIN_VAL when (rem_coin ='1') else y_sum ;



CNT_REG_P: process (clk)
begin
if (clk'event and clk ='1') then
    if (reset ='1') then 
        counter_reg <= to_unsigned(INIT_COUNT,counter_reg'length);
    elsif (en ='1') then
        counter_reg <= y_count;
    end if;
end if;
end process;



SUM_REG_P: process (clk)
begin
if (clk'event and clk ='1') then
    if (reset ='1') then 
        sum_reg <= INIT_SUM;
    elsif (en ='1') then
        sum_reg <= y_sum;
    end if;
end if;
end process;


count <= en_vec and std_logic_vector(counter_reg(4 downto 0));
fault <= ovf and en;
sum<= std_logic_vector(sum_reg);

end architecture rtl;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;

package fixed_point_pkg is
--There are up to 31 coins of each type, which gives the maximum value
--of 31 * 8.7 = 269.7. Hence we need 9 bits for the whole part. The
--smallest fraction we need to represent is 1/5, which is decently
--approximated by 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/128 (31 * error < 0.2). Hence, we
--need 7 more bits for the fractional part.
--The representation is thus 9:7.
constant fifth       : unsigned(15 downto 0) := x"0019";
--0000 0000 0.001 1001
constant half        : unsigned(15 downto 0) := x"0040";
--0000 0000 0.100 0000
constant one         : unsigned(15 downto 0) := x"0080";
--0000 0000 1.000 0000
constant two         : unsigned(15 downto 0) := x"0100";
--0000 0001 0.000 0000
constant five        : unsigned(15 downto 0) := x"0280";
--0000 0010 1.000 0000
function fixed_to_float(fixed : std_logic_vector) return real;
--Converts a 9.7 16-bit fixed point number to a real.
function float_to_fixed(float : real) return unsigned;
--Converts a real to a 9.7 16-bit fixed point number.
function float_eq(a : real; b : real) return boolean;
--Compares two floats by truncating them to two decimal points. 

type init_count_t is array(0 to 4) of natural;
--Represents the numbers of coins of each type loaded at maintenance.
--The first element corresponds to the 20 cents coins and the last to 5 franc ones.
type init_sum_t   is array(0 to 4) of unsigned(15 downto 0);
--Represents the total values of the coins of each type loaded at maintentance.
--The order is the same as for >>init_count_t<<.
constant main_init_counts : init_count_t := (20, 10, 10, 5, 0);
constant main_init_sums   : init_sum_t := (x"0200", x"0280", x"0500", x"0500", x"0000");
end package fixed_point_pkg;

package body fixed_point_pkg is
function fixed_to_float(fixed : std_logic_vector) return real is
    type val_t is array(15 downto 0) of real;
    constant vals : val_t := (256.0, 128.0, 64.0, 32.0, 16.0, 8.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0,
                              0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.015625, 0.0078125);
    variable sum  : real := 0.0;
begin
    for i in 0 to 15 loop
        if fixed(i) = '1' then
            sum := sum + vals(i);
        end if;
    end loop;
    return sum;
end function fixed_to_float;

function float_to_fixed(float : real) return unsigned is
begin
    return to_unsigned(integer(trunc(float * 128.0)), 16);
end function float_to_fixed;

function float_eq(a : real; b : real) return boolean is
    variable a_int, b_int : integer;
begin
    a_int := integer(trunc(a * 100.0));
    b_int := integer(trunc(b * 100.0));
    return a_int = b_int;
end function float_eq;

end package body fixed_point_pkg;
```

Comment: The nomenclature `tick` isn't clear, are you referring to delta simulation cycles? It also isn't clear from peering at this why you'd be concerned with delta cycle delays in a synchronous system. Where and how are `sum` and `count` being used that delta simulation cycles are of a concern?  Combinational derived signals should not be used either for clocks nor latch enables. Provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem you're trying to overcome.

Answer (score 0):

y_count is the input to a register, indicated by *else counter_reg*. y_sum is a latch, indicated by *else y_sum*, which is then registered. Replace *else y_sum* with *else sum_reg*.

Answer (score 0):

Try to draw a block diagram of the hardware you described, where are the registers, where are multiplexers, where adders etc. Then see if your tool supports a rtl netlist view so you can compare what you think you wrote with what you actually wrote. If you see any latches there see if you can rewrite your code/change your design to change those to registers. Latches an FPGAs don't go together well. Then you can follow the path for both signals an count how many registers each one "meets".